# UTF-8 not working on my web system (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, pdo

I have read a lot about utf8, so on my web system I have UTF8 set on the DB (tables and COLLATION), on the PDO connection, on every page with header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); Also I saved my files with "UTF8 without BOM".

So, this is my problem: I have a word gotten from the database "$row['palabra']", if I print that variable the output is "árbitro" (also I use the mb_detect_encoding php function to check, and is UTF8), but if I want to use a letter from that variable, like this: "$row['palabra'][1]" (I don't know why the index doesn't start in 0) I get this symbol because the letter "a" have an accent: �. Why?

ps: I need to use some letter comparison from this strings to do other things on my system.

Comment: "I don't know why the index doesn't start in 0" <-- that should be telling you something...

Comment: String functions and use of `[]` on a string work at the byte-level, not character-level; you need to use the [mb_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [mb_substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.mb-substr.php):

```
echo mb_substr($row['palabra'],0,1); //output: á
```

Comment: I still got a �... ps: add to "row" a $ ;)

Comment: I add the "encoding" parameter, and now works: mb_substr($row['palabra'],0,1,'utf-8') Thanks!